# Can't find function?

Tags: function, ms-access-2007

I have a Access 2007, split DB to 2008R2, multiple users and a problem that happens randomly.
The file opens with an AutoExec macro that tests for Trusted Content, 'Run Code' function OpenDB() that proceeds to call a DSNLess connection to link my BE tables.  All users use the same shortcut that points to a folder that houses the main form.  Some users get the msg box upon opening and enabling trusted content that the OpenDB() function can't be found.  The public function is clearly there and **not** named the same as the Module itself.  The fact that it happens randomly to different people baffles me.  It's not even getting to the first function to be called so I'm not sure where else to look it it can't even start.  Sometimes I can open the file (not from shortcut) from end users desktop, it opens fine and sometimes same error.  Close it, re-open from shortcut and it works.  Maybe.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use access trust center option try this guide it may help. http://ageesw.com/MACRO.htm